# ASP.NET Get Username for Logged-In User

Tags: asp.net

I have a class named `Store` which happens to have a property named `User`.

This `User` can later log-in into  the application.

**The Problem:**
What I attempt is to create a list of the `Stores` based on the `User` that is currently logged-in

*Example of `Store` table: Last column `Usuario a.k.a. User`*

[image]

What I have tried:

```
var Tiendas = await _context.Stores
.Where(t => t.Usuario= User.Identity.Name.ToString()).ToListAsync();
```

Is it a close attempt? I'm getting an error:

> Can't convert the type string into bool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Tiendas = await _context.Stores
.Where(t => t.Usuario == User.Identity.Name).ToListAsync();
```

Change your `t.Usuario = User.Identity.Name.ToString()` to `t.Usuario == User.Identity.Name`

You're using an assignment operator when you should be using a comparison operator.  Also you can remove the .ToString() since User.Identity.Name is a string already.